# Conditional rendering of tooltip doesn't seem to function correctly

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, antd

I have the following piece of code in my react with antd project

```
    return (
        { bUseTooltip && <Tooltip text='test'> }
        <Input
            type="text"
            value={value.strValue || strValue}
            onFocus={funcTriggerFocus}
            onChange={funcOnInputChange}
            onBlur={funcTriggerBlur}
            autoComplete="off"
            id={strId}
        />
        { bUseTooltip && </Tooltip> }
    );
```

What this should do is render the 'tooltip' element if 'bUseTooltip' has been set to true. Instead I'm getting compilation errors that a comma is expected.

```
  40:23  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  38 |
  39 |     return (
> 40 |         { bUseTooltip && <Tooltip text='test'> }
     |                       ^
  41 |         <Input
  42 |             type="text"
  43 |             value={value.strValue || strValue}

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

 @ ./src/components/form/FormItem/index.js 16:0-50 78:38-51
 @ ./src/domain/public/Login/index.jsx
 @ ./src/domain/public/Home/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App.jsx
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/components/input/TextField/index.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\Workspace\Projects\......\src\components\input\TextField\index.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (40:22)
```

It may be the babel config but I'm not sure. Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have to do with your component returning multiple Dom sibling elements that are not wrapped in a single parent component. Try wrapping your whole jsx in a react fragment component (<>... </>) and see if that works

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be part of the solution, it started doing more when I wrapped it in a new div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing closing tag for **Tooltip** component...

```
{ bUseTooltip && <Tooltip text='test' /> }
```

There are two way to close component tags

**1-** self closing

```
<Tooltip  />
```

**2-** Corresponding closing tag

```
<Tooltip> </Tooltip>
```

Comment: That would have been a way to go, but ant design expects the input element to be inside the tooltip element so that's why the closure tag was in a different condition at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Bit dumb of me. For it to work, I added additional `div` element to the return. It seems it only works then. So now my return is like this:

```
    return (
        <div>
            {value.bUseTooltip ? (
                <Tooltip
                    title={value.strTooltip}
                >
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        value={value.strValue || strValue}
                        onFocus={funcTriggerFocus}
                        onChange={funcOnInputChange}
                        onBlur={funcTriggerBlur}
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id={strId}
                    />
                </Tooltip>
            ) : (
                <Input
                    type="text"
                    value={value.strValue || strValue}
                    onFocus={funcTriggerFocus}
                    onChange={funcOnInputChange}
                    onBlur={funcTriggerBlur}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    id={strId}
                />            
            )}
        </div>
    );
```

It still doesn't like it if the start and end tags are in different conditions though. I'll play with that some other time. For now this can do, this component won't change 100 times, I might be able to move the input tag out of the return into a variable to not have to update it twice and keep them equal.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a previous answer, wrapping in a `<Fragment>` or `<>` did not work, but wrapping it in a `div` did work; not entirely sure about the inner workings.

**Works**

```
<Tooltip content={"item.name"} delayDuration={0} key={"tooltip" + item.name}>
  <div>
    <ListItem item={item} isCollapsed={isCollapsed} />
  </div>
</Tooltip>
```

Without the `<div>` wrapping the ListItem, it did not.